# Select and print all tables from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is my code I have no error but no data shown on my page. Some help please...what is wrong on my code? Thank you so mucH

```
<?php 
            if(logged_in() === true){

            $q=mysql_query("select *  from `admin` order by `id` desc");

            echo "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1><tr><td>Id</td><td>User</td><td>Password</td><td>Permission</td><td>delete</td><td>edit</td></tr>";

            while($date=mysql_fetch_row($q));
            echo "<tr><td>{$date[0]}</td><td>{$date[1]}</td><td>{$date[2]}</td><td>{$date[3]}</td><form method=post action=delete.php><td><input type=hidden name=id value='{$date[0]}'><input type=submit name=sterge value=delete></td></form><form action=edit.php method=get><td><input type=hidden name=id value='{$date[0]}'><input type=submit name=edit value=edit></td></td></form></tr>";

            echo "</table>";    

            }else {

            include 'includes/widgets/home.php';
            }

 ?>
```

Comment: Any error message? PHP can have a lot of different things going wrong so you'll need to activate warnings and debug info to find out what's going on.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: *They wouldn't know what to do with that Sam, even if it came with an one-step instructional manual*. - @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 3):

A few things, as with the below changes, it works with data coming back. I faked the `logged_in()` function by always returning true.

First thing, you had a semi-colon after your while right away. So that was bad. I put the ending `</table>` outside the while block.

Also, stay away from `select *`. Spell out the column names. And I suggest you use the column names and not ordinal values upon using them in the result set.

Also, move to `mysqli` or `pdo`. **Jay gave you links to them above in comments.**

```
$dbname = 'myDB';
$dbuser = 'GuySmiley';
$dbpass = 'anchovies';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");


if(logged_in() === true){

$q=mysql_query("select *  from `admin` order by `id` desc");
if($q === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // this is for non-production code
}


echo "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1><tr><td>Id</td><td>User</td><td>Password</td><td>Permission</td><td>delete</td><td>edit</td></tr>";

while($date=mysql_fetch_row($q)) 
{
    echo "<tr><td>{$date[0]}</td><td>{$date[1]}</td><td>{$date[2]}</td><td>{$date[3]}</td><form method=post action=delete.php><td><input type=hidden name=id value='{$date[0]}'><input type=submit name=sterge value=delete></td></form><form action=edit.php method=get><td><input type=hidden name=id value='{$date[0]}'><input type=submit name=edit value=edit></td></td></form></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "you are not logged in<br>";
}
```

[image]

**So it outputs your data** (and by turning on error reporting, developing code is a lot easier).

### Turn on error reporting

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Develop with non-deprecated mysql libraries with code wrapped in **exception handling**

---

By the way, schema for above test is

```
create table admin
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    col1 int not null,
    col2 int not null,
    col3 int not null
);
insert admin (col1,col2,col3) values (11,111,1111),(22,222,2222);
```

Comment: OP ran off with my ex-wife; good. Running off with this question/answer; not good.

Comment: Check out the OP's track record. Plus, their new question; poor guy's in for a long haul and no green ticky to boot; not even you buddy. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news here, but at least you've got the right time 'o day ;-)

Comment: wasn't a total loss; you've gotten some upvotes to boot. I usually check OP's track record first. Most of the time, you tell 'em how to close a question and they just say *"Meh.... f * ck it"*.

Comment: Some of them honestly don't know how Stack rolls. A gentle push in the right direction usually helps and many do do the right thing, while the sponges just keep on soaking it up.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of looks like

```
while($date=mysql_fetch_row($q));
       echo "<tr><td>{$date[0]}</td><td>{$date[1]}</td><td>{$date[2]}</td><td>{$date[3]}</td><form method=post action=delete.php><td><input type=hidden name=id value='{$date[0]}'><input type=submit name=sterge value=delete></td></form><form action=edit.php method=get><td><input type=hidden name=id value='{$date[0]}'><input type=submit name=edit value=edit></td></td></form></tr>";

        echo "</table>";
```

Should be

```
while($date=mysql_fetch_row($q)){
        echo "<tr><td>{$date[0]}</td><td>{$date[1]}</td><td>{$date[2]}</td><td>{$date[3]}</td><form method=post action=delete.php><td><input type=hidden name=id value='{$date[0]}'><input type=submit name=sterge value=delete></td></form><form action=edit.php method=get><td><input type=hidden name=id value='{$date[0]}'><input type=submit name=edit value=edit></td></td></form></tr>";

        echo "</table>"; 
}
```

Note the semicolon instead of the braces for the while loop